# Recommended way to retrieve the current user identity in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-authentication

I'm reviewing an application currently experiencing problems with authentication (forms authentication is used combined with a custom way to retrieve the current user's profile) and I've noticed that the user's identity is retrieved using different methods:

- Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity (on some http modules)
- HttpContext.Current.User.Identity (on some http modules and also pages)
- Page.User.Identity (on pages)

Is it safe to assume that the same value will always be returned by all methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` (on some http modules and also pages)
`Page.User.Identity` (on pages)

Both of them return an Instance of `IPrincipal`

`Page.User` uses the `HttpContext` object's User property to determine where the request originates

The best methos is `HttpContext.Current.User`

`Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity` won't show the right user if you use the Impersonation
and it will give you the windows user details instead

Comment: and what about Thread.CurrentPrincipal? That is the one I'm not sure about. Also is it kept in sync with the IPrincipal stored on the current HttpContext?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on the impersonation?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mind elaborating a little bit more on what is the main difference between the identity stored on the HttpContext and the one stored on the Thread? How they are set and maintained by Forms Authentication?

Comment: the Thread user is the user is executing the current thread (it may be also the window user logged on the server) which could be completely different from the one in the HttpContext.

Comment: Ideally I would have like more details on this topic but since you were the only one taking the time to answer I'm choosing your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The one we usually use is HttpContext.Current.User.Identity

Comment: That's also the one I consistently use. It's also my understanding that Page.User is a shortcut to HttpContext.Current.User. I'm curious about the identity stored on the Thread.CurrentPrincipal and if the are always in sync.